# Variables inside and outside a loop with/without asterix

Tags: c++

I am not proficient in C++ but I am converting a short script to PHP

```
for(auto it = First; it != Last; ++it)
{
    Result += *it;
}
```

From this snippet, I can speculate this simply means

```
Result = Result + it
```

where `*` is a reference to the pointer of the loop.

That said I see this symbol used outside of loops and in some cases I see variables without this symbol both in and outside of loops which puts holes in my theory.

Again I am trying to RTFM but I am unsure what I am searching for.

Comment: Don't theorize. Read a [book](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list).

Comment: Actually, `*` is a **de**-reference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both `First` and `Last` are *iterator objects*, representing a generalization of pointers in C++ Standard Library. Additionally, the two iterators reference the same collection, and `Last` can be reached from `First` by incrementing the iterator<sup>*</sup>.

`Result` is some sort of accumulator. If it is of numeric type, `+=` means `Result = Result + *it`, where `*it` is whatever the iterator is pointing to. In other words, `Result` *accumulates* the total of elements of the collection between `First`, inclusive, and `Last`, exclusive. If `First` points to the beginning of an array and `Last` points to one-past-the-end of an array of numeric type, your code would be equivalent to calling PHP `array_sum()` on the array.

However, `Result` is not required to be numeric. For example, it could be a `std::string`, in which case `+=` represents appending the value to the string.

<sup>*</sup> In terms of pointers and arrays this would be "pointing to the same array," and "`Last` points to a higher index of the array than `First`."

Answer (score 0):

I believe your speculation is incorrect.

`it`, `first` and `last` are either *iterators* or *pointers*. Iterators are C++ objects that can be used to iterator over containers. For basic usage, they behave much like pointers, and can be dereferenced the same way.

For example:

```
std::vector<int> myList;

...

// Search for the number 10 in the list.
std::vector<int>::iterator it = std::find(myList.begin(), myList.end(), 10);

// If the number 10 was found in the list, change the value to 11.
if (it != myList.end())
    *it = 11;  //< Similar to pointer syntax.
```

In your specific example, the `Result` variable has a value added to it. To get that value, your code uses the `*` operator to get the value from the iterator.

The same concept applies to pointers. although iterators and pointers are very different concepts, accessing their values is very similar.